# Cannot get the total cost of all items in Cart

Tags: angular

I am attempting to get the total cost of all the items in the cart. I am able to get the total for each {{item.rate * item.quantity}}, but I am not able to find the  total sum of all items in the cart.

**estimate-detail.component.html**

```html
<tbody>
        <tr *ngFor=" let item of Items">
            <td>
            <a cart-button [item]="item" action="remove" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">
                X
            </a>
            </td>
            <td>{{item.itemName}}</td>
            <td>{{item.rate}}</td>
            <td>

           <custom-counter [(counter)]="item.quantity"></custom-counter>

           </td>
            <td>${{item.rate*item.quantity | number: '.2'}}</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
      <tfoot>
      <tr>
          <td colSpan="4" class="text-right">Total</td>
          <td>${{ Items | cartTotal | number: '.2'}}</td>
      </tr>
      </tfoot>
```

**totalPipe.ts**

```js
 import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

 @Pipe({name: 'cartTotal'})
 export class TotalPipe implements PipeTransform {

transform(value) {
        console.log("here");
    let total = 0;
    if (value) {
        value.forEach(item => {
            total += item.quantity * item.rate;
        });
    }
    return total;
}
 }
```

I am able to call the pipe, but it does not update the total.

**counter.component.ts**

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'custom-counter',
  template: `
    <button (click)="decrement()">-</button>
    <span>{{counter}}</span>
    <button (click)="increment()">+</button>
  `
})
export class CustomCounterComponent {
 counterValue = 0;
  @Output() counterChange = new EventEmitter();

  @Input()
  get counter() {
    return this.counterValue;
  }

  set counter(val) {
    this.counterValue = val;
    this.counterChange.emit(this.counterValue);
  }

  decrement() {
    this.counter--;
  }

  increment() {
    this.counter++;
  }
}
```

Comment: Please provide plunker.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but `total` must be `this.total`, right ? Something like : `this.total += item.quantity * item.rate;` and `return this.total;`

Comment: Hello, Im not sure how to create a plunker. The Items are generated via an api.

Comment: @mickdev No, it's correct. `total` is a local var. Mason, try to put a `console.log` before the `return` statement on your `pipe`.

Comment: @developer033 The console log works before the return statement.         `transform(value) {
            console.log("here");
        let total = 0;
        if (value) {
            value.forEach(item => {
                total += item.quantity * item.rate;
            });
        }
        console.log(total);
        return total;
    }`      but the value is still zero

Comment: @Masonbelyeu If it's 0 maybe the array is empty or the values inside it are 0. Check the array..

Comment: @developer033 you are right. I tried to console.log(value) and it's undefined.

Comment: For edit version: Maybe the `pipe` isn't showing the values as you're expecting because it's pure, in other words, it doesn't **watch** for changes in array.

Answer (score 1):

`*ngFor=" let item of Items"` is Items with capital i.

`${{ items | cartTotal | number: '.2'}}` is items with lowercase i.

Thus, change `items` to `Items`, or alternatively change the property in your component to `items` and it should work.

Comment: thanks we are heading in the right direction..the only issue is that I would like to sum the quantity generated by `<custom-counter [(counter)]="item.quantity"></custom-counter>` Currently, its using the initial value set in the Items object. I will update the code to show the custom counter.